# how to convert a=1000000000 to a decimal number 0 b=0100000000 to decimal number 1 and so on for 9 numerals

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data set that contains ten columns and 3000 rows. Each of the column contains a 0 or 1. The ten columns concatenated together represent a label. There are ten labels from 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. The concatenated  sequences like "1000000000" represents the label zero and "0100000000" represents label one (the number 1) and "0000000001" represents label nine.

What is the best/efficient code to convert these sequences into labels and add it as the eleventh column to the data set

1. for loop
2. lambda function
3. masking
4. binary and operation

I am confused and  currently I am trying to write a lambda function to do this which is getting me nowhere?

```
target1 = target.apply(lambda x: [print(x)  for j in range(10) for i in x], axis = 1)
```

I would like to know which method I should use to implement this pattern matching .

Initial Data frame

```
data = [[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Final data with the eleventh column name label

```
[dataframe][label]
1000000000  0   
0100000000  1  
0010000000  2  
0001000000  3  
0000100000  4  
0000010000  5  
0000001000  6  
0000000100  7  
0000000010  8  
0000000001  9
```

Comment: Are there any such columns with more than one `1` in the value?

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataframe and the expected output here? I'm now confused about what actual column data you have. If you have 10 separate columns and not a single column, then that's a different proposition from having a single column containing a string with 10 digits (9 `'0'` characters and 1 `'1'` character).

Comment: All 10 columns contain only 0 or 1. Yes there are ten seperate columns each having only 0 or 1.

Comment: So are these the names of the columns, or the column values? If these are values, what is the dtype of those columns, and will there only ever be a single column with a 1 in it on a given row? This would all be a lot easier with a concrete example in your question, code that creates a simple dataframe, and your expected output.

Comment: So are these the names of the columns, or the column values? ==> these are col values. dtype of column is integer. yes there will be only a single column with 1 in any given row

Comment: The question has been reworded  and the code to create the data frame included

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively looking for the column index with the maximum value, so you can use [`Dataframe.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html#pandas.DataFrame.idxmax), with `axis=1` to apply to the values across each row:

```
df['label'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

Note that if you have *additional* columns than just the 10 numeric columns, you'd want to first select only the 10 numeric columns; e.g. `df.iloc[:, range(10)].idxmax(...)`.

Demo:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = [[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
...         [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
...         [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
...         [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
...         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df['label'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  label
0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      1
2  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      2
3  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0      3
4  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0      4
5  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0      5
6  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0      6
7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0      7
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0      8
9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1      9
```

---

I had advocated using `Series.idxmax()` via `Dataframe.apply()` at first, but in a now-deleted comment Jezrael reminded me that `Dataframe.idxmax()` also exists and is much more practical here.

Comment: @jezrael: and it stands to reason that the method is available on a dataframe too. I should have looked for that.

Comment: I wonder which one is faster `df.idxmax(axis=1)` or the matrix multiplication (see below). Somebody should `%timeit` … :-)

Answer (score 0):

#### 1.let's generate a pandas DF

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 10
#---let's generate a pandas DF
M =  np.identity(n,dtype=int); M = np.vstack((M,M))
np.random.shuffle(M)
PD = pd.DataFrame(M)
print(PD)

#--- that's the label vector
vLabel = np.arange(n,dtype=int)
```

So we get:

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0   0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
1   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
3   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
5   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
6   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
7   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
11  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
12  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
13  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
14  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
15  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
16  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
17  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
18  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
19  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
```

#### 2. the labeling is a matrix-vector multiplication

```
#--- the labeling is a matrix-vector multiplication 
Label = np.dot(PD,vLabel)
print(Label)
```

So we get:

```
[6 5 9 2 3 5 9 1 0 1 8 0 3 8 2 7 4 4 7 6]
```

#### 3. Each row can be transformed into a string

```
#---- each row can be transformed into a string
for j in range(2*n):
    print(str(PD.values[j,:]))
```

So we get:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

And from here you can continue :-)

Note: point 2. (matrix multiplication) is efficient, point 3. (for loop) is not efficient, so you might improve this step.